# What has happened to books from world of "Paranoia" published by "Ultraviolet books"?

Tags: books, paranoia

Attention citizens! This might be a treasonous attack by evil communist mutants carrying the evil mark of John Lennon, but I am unable to find anywhere any fictions published by the Ultraviolet Books about our Wonderful Complex Alpha and our beloved Friend Computer!

I know there have been at least 4 books published (I am especially looking for the "***A1 Computer is your friend***" since I've manage to read the sneak peak and "T1 Stay Alert", both by Allen Varney", but all the links that I can find point to dead pages. Do I have too low clearance to find them or are we under attack?

**In all seriousness, what happened to the novels and why did they suddenly disappear from view?**

Comment: Might this be more appropriate to ask on the RPG stack exchange?

Comment: well... its about fiction books, so the proper forum is bit blurred.

Comment: Trust no one and keep your laser handy! We are surrounded by mutants and secret societies and commie traitor spies! They might be trying to close this very question!

Comment: @Yasskier Ah I see... I stand enlightened. And will be happy to report your conceptual "blurriness!" Happiness results from a well-ordered mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked my good friend [Alan Varney](https://twitter.com/AllenVarney/status/642078005892894720?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) about this. The short answer is that when he failed to renew the rights licence, it appears that he was obliged to remove the links to the books:

> [@AllenVarney](https://twitter.com/AllenVarney) - Wondering what's happened to ultravioletbooks and your ebooks (A1 Computer is your friend, etc) They all seem to have gone...— Answerguesser401 (@Answerguesser40) [September 10, 2015](https://twitter.com/Answerguesser40/status/642071114135535616)

> [@Answerguesser40](https://twitter.com/Answerguesser40) The UV Books line sold poorly, and when the license expired I pulled the books and didn't renew it. Sorry!— Allen Varney (@AllenVarney) [September 10, 2015](https://twitter.com/AllenVarney/status/642078005892894720)

Comment: So in other words the books are... gone forever?

Comment: @Yasskier - Unless you can find them online, through a dodgy source. You could try emailing the author and asking for a copy.

Comment: I did and he shared them with me! Yay!